# what can prevent auto rebuilding the R class?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I have a strange problem with ADT and Eclipse at the moment. The R file does not get rebuilt automatically - I always have to do a clean to see the changes ( e.g. after inserting a string in strings.xml). I use ADT 21 and Eclipse 3.8 - any idea where I can look into to resolve this problem?

Comment: Look for the `Build Automatically` flag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting to `build automatically` in eclipse could be disabled but there could also be an error in one of the xml files. Usually just cleaning then building is enough to get rid of it altogether but you could also try deleting R then clean/build.